# Vue JS - Setting variable to vueObject.dataItem and modifying it also modifies the Vue data item

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

This behavior is causing problems in my projects. This is a simplified version of what’s happening. I’d like to learn why this happens, and how I can avoid it.
I have vue loaded in the head of my website:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.21/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

And this is the Vue object:

```
vueObject = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
"array": []
}
});
```

Now, my issue is this. How do I save a copy of the “array” data item from the Vue Object so I can manipulate it without actually modifying the real array Vue data item?
This is what I’m trying to do, but it isn’t working as intended;

```
var arrayCopy = vueObject.array;
arrayCopy.push("x");
```

This is causing both arrayCopy and vueObject.array to be set to [“x”].
I only want to add “x” to arrayCopy.
How can I do that? Why does this happen?

Comment: Well, the hacky way is `let copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(vueObject.array))`

Comment: why are you putting that logic outside of vue instance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48363604/vuejs-copying-data-object-and-removing-property-will-remove-the-property-from-or

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim This is not my actual project. This is a simplified example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're referencing the `vueObject.array` by doing `var arrayCopy = vueObject.array;` not copying it to `arrayCopy`, so to avoid that use `let arrayCopy = vueObject.array.slice();` or `Object.assign(arrayCopy, vueObject.array)`

```js
let vueObject = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    array: ['a', 'b']
  }
});

let arrayCopy = vueObject.array.slice();
arrayCopy.push('x');

console.log(arrayCopy);
console.log( vueObject.array);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been using JS for a while and I've never noticed this. You learn something new every day :)

Answer (score 2):

Objects are [assigned by reference](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0). When you assign an array, you are just making another variable refer to the same object. Modifying the *contents* of an object will be reflected in everything that references that object.

An [array copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copy-array-by-value) would be `arrayCopy = vueObject.array.slice()`, but the same caveat applies to any Objects contained in the array: if you modify their contents, those modifications will show up in both arrays. See more answers in the linked thread about deep copying.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to create a new Array and spread the vue data array inside the new array so we copy all its original values, but then manipulate it as it's own context.

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    array: [1, 2, 3]
  },
  created: function() {
    this.doSomething();
  },
  methods: {
    doSomething() {
      const copy = [...this.array];
      copy.push(4);
      console.log("copy:", copy);
      console.log("origninal", this.array);
    }
  }
});
```